# PHP 7.2 cURL with OpenSSL not SecureTransport

Tags: php, curl, openssl, homebrew

I have a local PHP install on a Mac that out of the box uses cURL 7.54.0 w/SecureTransport for SSL. I need to switch this to use a version of cURL that uses OpenSSL for SSL. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Install OpenSSL using brew: `brew install openssl`
2. Install cURL with OpenSSL using brew: `brew install curl --with-openssl`
3. Reinstall PHP from the source with the `--with-curl=/usr/local/opt/curl` option set. This path is the cURL with OpenSSL, the built-in one exists.

Based on what I've researched, this should be the solution, but when I open up phpinfo() PHP is **still** using the old curl 7.54.0 w/SecureTransport. The **Configure Command** secure shows that `'--with-curl=/usr/local/opt/curl'` was properly set during the configure process.

Down under **http** I do see something interesting going on with `libcurl`:

```
Used Library    Compiled    Linked
libcurl         7.59.0      7.54.0
```

I have no idea how to adjust the `Linked` item shown here, or if this will even fix the issue. I'm completely stumped, any help is extremely appreciated.